# Is it possible to use grub2win on Windows when the system partition is encrypted with VeraCrypt?

Tags: veracrypt

I have succesfully encrypted my Windows partition (system partition) with VeraCrypt. I can login into Windows after entering the correct VeraCrypt password.
I have the following physical drives:

- Drive 1: Windows, encrypted with Veracrypt.
- Drive 2: Linux, encrypted with Luks.

Is it possible to install and use grub2win on Windows so after entering the Veracrypt password I can login into Linux? I have not found documentation on this topic and I'm hesitant to just try it because I dont know if i could make the Windows OS unbootable.

Note: I have found that it is possible to do the opposite: using linux grub2 to boot Windows Veracrypt encrypted partition but I see that it is a bit complex so I want to avoid it.

So far I need to use the bios 'boot menu' if I need to select which OS to boot but it is not the ideal solution.

I know that this boot OS selection works ok with UEFI but my motherboard does not have UEFI, it is just BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and tried installing grub2win on Windows and it worked ok. I'll post the answer here so maybe it will be useful to someone:

After installing grub2win you need to go to the 'mange boot menu' option and you need to add an entry to boot from the linux drive. On the 'type' option you need to select the option to 'chainload a disk'. On the 'Disk drive to chainload' you need to select the linux drive number (0 is the first drive) as reported by the bios. On my case the first drive reported by bios is the windows drive and the second one is the linux drive so on this case I selected '1'.

By doing this the linux grub2 menu will be launched after selecting this option on the grub2win grub menu. It works ok even if the linux partition is encrypted with Luks. The only downside is that if you want to boot into linux first you need to enter the veracrypt password and later the luks password.